# Receive HTTP post data and return ok(200)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, http, response

There is a third party providing me data. I give them my (endpoint) which is my application server(website), and they send me a POST.

I would like to receive the data and return a Ok.

I am guessing I should have some httpclient and httpresponse message on my home page?
It shouldn't be that hard, but I can't figure this one out.
I am using asp.net MVC web application in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you successfully return a View for example the HTTP status code will be 200. If you want to force a return of 200, set it on the Response object.

```
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    return View("Index", model);
```

If you are using WebAPI, you can assign the return HTTP status code.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Foo()
{
    // Your logic

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); // OK = 200
}
```